# Medalhas e chapéu desaparecem

Tags: suporte, status-pronto

Em algumas páginas aparecem assim:

[image: chapéu e 3 medalhas desapareceram]

Em outras páginas aparecem assim:

[image: correto]

Porque medalhas e chapéu desaparecem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provavelmente o primeiro é este site aqui, o meta, e o segundo é o site principal.

Não sei explicar porque mas não tem chapéu no meta. E as medalhas são mais ou menos separadas.  Alguém sabe o critério de distribuição? Pelo que vejo algumas medalhas vem para ambos, outras vale apenas para onde ela foi ganha.

A pontuação é que é a mesma, o meta não tem pontuação, ele sempre carrega a reputação obtida no principal.

Comment: Aparentemente é isto mesmo que você disse. Obrigado

Comment: Existem medalhas que ganhamos no site principal por valorização do trabalho realizado no site META, exemplo da medalha "[Quórum](http://br.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/67/quorum)" do site principal. Mas não sei de nenhuma que uma vez ganha num dos sites, passe para o outro.

Answer (score 4):

## Introdução às medalhas e chapéus

As medalhas e chapéus dizem respeito à reputação do utilizador:

#### Medalhas:

Cada site tem a sua atribuição distinta de medalhas ao utilizador pelo trabalho que o mesmo realiza no site em questão e/ou reputação adquirida.

#### Chapéus:

Os chapéus são uma forma de animar determinadas épocas do ano, que, tal como as medalhas, são atribuídos pela reputação que o utilizador vai adquirindo (fruto do seu trabalho no site em questão).

## Porque a diferença que reportaste

Todos os sites META que não o site principal http://meta.stackoverflow.com, não estão sujeitos a ganhos de reputação independente do seu site principal, pelo que os chapéus não se podem aplicar.

Já no http://meta.stackoverflow.com, como o ganho de reputação é independente do seu site principal (https://stackoverflow.com/), os chapéus são possíveis de ganhar, pelo que são utilizados.

---

#### A saber:

O único site META com pontuação distinta do site principal é o http://meta.stackoverflow.com, todos os outros existem apenas para permitir discussão sobre melhoramentos ao seu respetivo site principal.

Quando o assunto é genérico a todos os sites o consenso é que a pergunta deve ser colocada no http://meta.stackoverflow.com, sendo aí a área de discussão não só para o https://stackoverflow.com/ como para toda a StackExchange.